# UFW python documentation

Tags: python, firewall, ufw

I'm trying to access `ufw` with python, but on line 53 of `backend.py`, they raise a weird error  that makes no sense:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymodule.py", line 1467, in <module>
      print backend.UFWBackend('notused', False).get_rules()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ufw/backend.py", line 53, in __init__
      self._read_rules()
AttributeError: UFWBackend instance has no attribute '_read_rules'
```

Here's the code that raises this error:

```
backend.UFWBackend('notused', False).get_rules()
```

There are minimal comments and doc strings throughout all of the code, and there unused and undeclared attributes and methods every where, so it's been complicated to navigate.

Comment: It doesn't fix it, but I think I figured it out. After what I just found out, there's no way the guy who wrote this didn't make it hard to read on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found it. Without **any** comments/documentation or obvious pythonic errors, they just let it break with something that doesn't tell you what's going on. Instead of raising a [NotImplementedError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError), they just let it fail with an `AttributeError`. It just doesn't feel like how open source code should work, but what do I know.

But as for my answer: **I need to subclass the `UFWBackend` class and implement the methods myself.**